# Set up an interceptor in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I am trying to cope with the SOP and I need to setup a filter and an interceptor, according to  http://patrickgrimard.com/2013/12/12/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-requests-with-spring-mvc/.
I setup the filter in the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>base.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

where SimpleCORSFilter is

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Content-Type");  
    filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

It works, because my test POST request is caught and manipulated. Now, I tried to config the following interceptor:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return true;
}
}
```

and I added the following configuration in the rest-servlet.xml (which works, as the REST service are correctly invoked):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lh.clte.web" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/*" />
        <bean class="base.SimpleCORSInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

However, the overridden method is not getting called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article the filter is intended **only** for requests using the `OPTION` method, whereas the interceptor is meant for the "real" calls. In your example all requests would be handled by both the filter and the interceptor. So you don't need the interceptor.

Moreover the interceptor is only called when there is a controller method handling the request. When you call a URL that is not mapped, then the interceptor is not called.

BTW: There's no need for `@Component`.

Comment: I am talcking about mapped urls. I understand your point, but why the Interceptor is not being called? Also, if I disable the interceptor, the CORS filter is not working properly. In fact, SOP still affects my application negatively.

Comment: @Manu What exactly do you mean by "_if I disable the interceptor, the CORS filter is not working properly._"? The interceptor has no effect on the filter. I'm not sure if the headers are handled in a case insensitive way. Maybe it has to be `X-Requested-With`.

Comment: I mean that I still cannot get responses with status different from 0 when invoking REST services from the GWT client to the Spring server. Unfortunately, it is not an issue of capital letters in the header.

Comment: @Manu Can you post the request and response (headers)?

Comment: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With;Content-Type

Comment: @Manu And the request headers?

Comment: Thanks, it was a matter of headers. While the response headers were fine, the appropriate request headers only include content-type.